# How to retrieve data from DB and turn them to object in my case?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, postgresql

I am using postgres `row_to_json` function to get the data that were stored through `JSON.stringify()`. However, when I retrieve it and do `JSON.parse()`, it gave me "`unexpected token ,`" error message.

My original data from frontend:

```
{ 
  "company":[
     {"name":"test company"},
     {"ceo":"John"}
   ]
}
```

I do `JSON.stringify(myData.company)` and store it to postgres.

When I retrieve it, I have `row_to_json` function to get the data.

and the `console.log(myRetrieveData)` become

```
{"{\"name\":\"test company\"}","{\"ceo\":\"John\"}"}
```

I used `JSON.parse(myRetrieveData)` and got '`unpexted token ,`' error.

I understand `row_to_json` turn it into json and can't be used on `JSON.parse` but the function is needed for my other data. 
I am not sure how to fix this. Can anyone help me about it? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the JSON that you retrieved from the query is not of the proper format for it to be parsed. Inorder to avoid this please make sure that the JSON being stored into the DB is of proper JSON format, so that it parsed.If this is not achievable the response obtained from the db has to be modified to proper JSON. With the above data it can be done as follows.

```
var improperJson = '{"{\"name\":\"test company\"}","{\"ceo\":\"John\"}"}';
var properJson = improperJson.replace(/","/g, ",").replace(/^{"/, "[").replace(/"}$/, "]");
console.log(JSON.parse(properJson));//should give you the parsed JSON
```

Comment: Can you add the `console.log` output of properJson from your code

Comment: Sure.   [{\"name\":\"test company\"},{\"ceo\":\"john\"}]

Comment: `JSON.parse` seems to work fine for the above string

Comment: Thanks found the problem now.